# Webpack - Unable to load bundle.js with $.getScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I'm trying to load bundle.js which contains the code compiled through webpack using jquery `$.getScript`. However, it display blank page. But when I tried regular script tag then it works. The reason for using `$.getScript`is because I have two environments and I want to load additional scripts only during production environment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Single Page Program Demo</title>

    <script src="../Programs/2999/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        /* Environment - (options: development / production) */
        var env = 'development';

        /* Load all scripts related to pi shell integration in sequence */
        $.getMultiScripts = function(arr, path) {
            var _arr = $.map(arr, function(scr) {
                return $.getScript( (path||"") + scr );
            });

            _arr.push($.Deferred(function( deferred ){
                $( deferred.resolve );
            }));

            return $.when.apply($, _arr);
        }

        var script_arr;

        if (env == 'production'){

            script_arr = [
                'jquery-2.2.3.min.js', 
                'json2.js', 
                'jquery.validate.min.js',
                'PIH.PIPlatform.ClientSideStorage.js',
                'jquery.idletimer.js',
                'jquery.idletimeout.js',
                'DataTransfer.js',
                'pi_utility.js',
                'pi_data.js',
                'bundle.js'
            ];
        } 

        else {
            script_arr = [
                'bundle.js'
            ];
        }

        $.getMultiScripts(script_arr, '../Programs/2999/js/').done();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <!-- This works -->
    <!-- <script src="../Programs/2999/js/bundle.js"></script> -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Check this https://github.com/ded/script.js/ Have used this successfully in our project.

Comment: Coudn't you bundle two different files? One for production and another for dev?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it will be better to use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to manage your scripts.